# Is there a way to edit last Octave command and /or script typed in Octave CLI

Tags: command-line, octave, edit, history

typing and executing a single line command in octave cli is simple. 
for example `a=1`. 
If one wants to edit this command and execute it again it is possible by navigating the history with the up/down keys.

But when executing a multi line command-script, one can still navigate to a single line and edit it, but how to execute the all script again, without going line by line in the history and "enter" the line?
for example:

```
for i=1:6
a(i) = i;
end
```

Is there a way to open the all script in an editor, edit, and re-execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, via the `history` command.

E.g. `history -q 3` will display the last 3 commands -- the `-q` switch means do not prepend line numbers, such that the output is copy-pasteable.

You can also use the `-w` switch to redirect the output to a file, which you could then modify in your editor and call as a script, as you suggest.

If you're using the GUI, you can also use the history pane to highlight the lines you're interested in (in the order that you want them!), and paste directly into the editor window.